# Mongodb: How can I make some fields of certain records uppercase?

Tags: mongodb, replace

I'm aware this is a very simple question, but I don't seem to be able to find a satisfactory answer. Also, I'm a total newbie to Mongo. That clearly doesn't help.

Let's say I have a collection of... users, and I want to apply the [$toUpper](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/) function in mongo to the `name` field of the records with _id `ObjectId(1)` and `ObjectId(2)` but not to the one with `ObjectId(3)`.

So I have this:

```
{
    [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),
            "name": "user 1",
            "address": "Street 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("2"),
            "name": "user 2",
            "address": "Street 2"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("3"),
            "name": "user 3",
            "address": "Street 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I'd like to have:

```
{
    [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("1"),
            "name": "USER 1",
            "address": "Street 1"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("2"),
            "name": "USER 2",
            "address": "Street 2"
        },
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("3"),
            "name": "user 3",
            "address": "Street 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been playing with Mongo's [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) (for what I found in google), but the furthest I got is having a query that returns the "name" fields *uppered*, but:

1. It returns all the records in the DB (not only ObjectId("1") and
   ObjectId("2")
2. It doesn't write the changes in the database
3. It removes the *address* field from the returned record (which needless to say, I don't want to lose)

---

```
db.user.aggregate([{$project: {"name":{$toUpper:"$name"}}}])
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
            "name" : "USER 1"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
            "name" : "USER 2"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
            "name" : "USER 3"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you wan't update registers to change the field name to uppercase you can try this code:

```
use DATABASE_NAME;
db.CollectionName.find([find_criteria]).forEach(function(doc) { 
   db.CollectionName.update(
       { _id: doc._id},
       { $set : { 'FieldName' : doc.FieldName.toUpperCase() } },
       { multi: true }
   )
});
```